# Path finding in undirected fully connected graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory

I have an undirected fully connected graph. I have a start node and there is no end node. My nodes and edges don't have weights. Any **path** on the graph has some value. I can only know this value after going in this **entire** path. Path length is limited, but it can be very large.

For example:

[image]

It might be that:

- The value of the path `node1 -> node2` is 1
- The value of the path `node1 -> node3` is 1
- The value of the path `node1 -> node2 -> node3` is 2
- The value of the path `node1 -> node3 -> node2` is 20

My goal is to find some path with small value without traversing all possible paths. The smallest the value, the better.

I cannot use any familiar shortest-path algorithm like *Dijkstra* or *Floyd-Warshall* since i don't have an end node nor known weights in advance.

I was thinking on the following simple algorithm:

1. Starting from the start node, go to some other node. Evaluate the path.
2. From the next node, go to some other node. Evaluate the path. If the path's value is larger than before, go back and try another node.

Is there a known algorithm for that problem?

Thanks

Comment: So basically, path weights aren't known, end node isn't known, number of paths that you can traverse is also unknown. I don't think any existing graph algorithm would solve this, since there isn't any info to begin with. Your approach of retaining the path with the least weight seems to be greedily the best way out in this case imo

Comment: Your suggested algorithm seems to imply that extending a path can't make the path's value decrease. If this is true, then the smallest value path is a single edge. If this is not true and you don't have any more info on the value function, then you can't possibly do better than brute force enumeration